# Error Upgrade ubuntu 16.04 to 18

Tags: upgrade

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-distutils is already the newest version (3.6.5-3).
python3-distutils set to manually installed.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 debhelper : Depends: dh-autoreconf (>= 17~) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: dh-strip-nondeterminism (>= 0.028~) but 0.015-1 is to be installed
 libglib2.0-bin : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.56.1-2ubuntu1) but 2.48.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libglib2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.56.1-2ubuntu1) but 2.48.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libhtml-parser-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.26.0-4) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5 is to be installed
                       Depends: perlapi-5.26.0
 libnet-ssleay-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.26.1-4build1) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5 is to be installed
                      Depends: perlapi-5.26.1
 libxml-parser-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.26.0-4) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5 is to be installed
                      Depends: perlapi-5.26.0
 python3-distutils : Depends: python3 (>= 3.6.4-1~) but 3.5.1-3 is to be installed
 python3-lib2to3 : Depends: python3 (>= 3.6.4-1~) but 3.5.1-3 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Do specify the commands you are using.

Comment: you didn't done `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` or `sudo apt install -f` before trying to do the upgrade to 18.04

Comment: You seem to have packages from PPAs, third-party sources, and/or imported packages from the wrong version of Ubuntu. All of those may potentially cause a *version conflict* like you seem to have. Read the error messages carefully - apt is complaining about wrong versions. Disable all PPAs and other non-Ubuntu sources, and uninstall ALL packages from those sources. Downgrade or uninstall ALL wrong-version packages. Return your Ubuntu packages to as close to stock condition as possible before trying the release-upgrade again. Fully backup your data in case a reinstall is needed.

Answer (score -1):

this solution worked for me `sudo aptitude update` then `sudo aptitude upgrade`